# What does matrix**2 mean in python/numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a python ndarray temp in some code I'm reading that suffers this:

```
x = temp**2
```

Is this the dot square (ie, equivalent to m.*m) or the matrix square (ie m must be a square matrix)?  In particular, I'd like to know whether I can get rid of the transpose in this code:

```
temp = num.transpose(whatever)
num.sum(temp**2,axis=1))
```

and turn it into this:

```
num.sum(whatever**2,axis=0)
```

That will save me at least 0.1ms, and is clearly worth my time.
Thanks!  The ** operator is ungooglable and I know nothing!
a

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's just the square of each element.

```
from numpy import *
a = arange(4).reshape((2,2))
print a**2
```

prints

```
[[0 1]
 [4 9]]
```

Comment: You're welcome. (I signed back into point out the probably obvious note, that if you're ndarray are >2 dimensions, I don't think the transposing, axis swapping thing will work.)

Comment: I can see where this might be confusing.  Without knowing Python, and understanding that for real (and complex) numbers squaring means "multiply a number by itself", it would have been reasonable to assume that it meant "multiply a matrix by itself" for matricies.  This means that the matrix has equal numbers of rows and columns, of course.

Answer (score 6):

You should read [NumPy for Matlab Users](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html). The elementwise power operation is mentioned there, and you can also see that in numpy, some operators apply differently to `array` and `matrix`.

```
>>> from numpy import *
>>> a = arange(4).reshape((2,2))
>>> print a**2
[[0 1]
 [4 9]]
>>> print matrix(a)**2
[[ 2  3]
 [ 6 11]]
```

Answer (score 5):

`**` is the raise-to-power operator in Python, so `x**2` means "x squared" in Python -- including numpy. Such operations in numpy always apply element by element, so `x**2` squares each element of array `x` (whatever number of dimensions) just like, say, `x*2` would double each element, or `x+2` would increment each element by two (in each case, `x` proper is unaffected -- the result is a new temporary array of the same shape as `x`!).

**Edit**: as @kaizer.ze points out, while what I wrote holds for `numpy.array` objects, it doesn't apply to `numpy.matrix` objects, where multiplication means matrix multiplication rather than element by element operation like for `array` (and similarly for raising to power) -- indeed, that's the key difference between the two types. As the [Scipy tutorial](http://www.scipy.org/SciPy_Tutorial) puts it, for example:

> When we use numpy.array or
>   numpy.matrix there is a difference.
>   A*x will be in the latter case matrix
>   product, not elementwise product as
>   with array.

i.e., as the [numpy reference](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) puts it:

> A matrix is a specialized 2-d array
>   that retains its 2-d nature through
>   operations. It has certain special
>   operators, such as `*` (matrix
>   multiplication) and `**` (matrix power).

Comment: Well it is sadly not so simple, as I answered; the differing behaviors of `array` and `matrix` can confuse this, and operators such as `*` and `**` change meaning! (If A * B is matrix multiplication whith A, B matrix, A**2 has to be matrix exponentiation of course.)

Comment: Yes, there's a difference between matrix and array -- though `**` is of course still the raise-to-power operation, operations on a matrix apply to "the matrix", on an array to "the elements". Good point, let me edit to clarify.